# Why GPS tracker extends Service

Tags: android, android-location, android-gps

For using the android location based services we use the GPS tracker class which extends Service and implements LocationListener interface. What is the use of Service class here ? Is it only for getting the location updates in the background or something more ?

Example code below :

```
public class GPSTracker extends Service implements LocationListener {

   private final Context mContext;

   // flag for GPS status
   boolean isGPSEnabled = false;

   // flag for network status
   boolean isNetworkEnabled = false;

   // flag for GPS status
   boolean canGetLocation = false;

   Location location; // location
   double latitude; // latitude
   double longitude; // longitude

   // The minimum distance to change Updates in meters
   private static final long MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 10; // 10 meters

   // The minimum time between updates in milliseconds
   private static final long MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES = 1000 * 60 * 1; // 1 minute

   // Declaring a Location Manager
   protected LocationManager locationManager;

   public GPSTracker(Context context) {
      this.mContext = context;
      getLocation();
   }

   public Location getLocation() {
      try {
         locationManager = (LocationManager) mContext.getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

         // getting GPS status
         isGPSEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

         // getting network status
         isNetworkEnabled = locationManager
            .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

         if (!isGPSEnabled && !isNetworkEnabled) {
            // no network provider is enabled
         } else {
            this.canGetLocation = true;
            // First get location from Network Provider
            if (isNetworkEnabled) {
               locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                  LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
                  MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                  MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);

               Log.d("Network", "Network");
               if (locationManager != null) {
                  location = locationManager
                     .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

                  if (location != null) {
                     latitude = location.getLatitude();
                     longitude = location.getLongitude();
                  }
               }
            }

            // if GPS Enabled get lat/long using GPS Services
            if (isGPSEnabled) {
               if (location == null) {
                  locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                     LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                     MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                     MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);

                  Log.d("GPS Enabled", "GPS Enabled");
                  if (locationManager != null) {
                     location = locationManager
                        .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

                     if (location != null) {
                        latitude = location.getLatitude();
                        longitude = location.getLongitude();
                     }
                  }
               }
            }
         }

      } catch (Exception e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      }

      return location;
   }

   /**
      * Stop using GPS listener
      * Calling this function will stop using GPS in your app
   * */

   public void stopUsingGPS(){
      if(locationManager != null){
         locationManager.removeUpdates(GPSTracker.this);
      }
   }

   /**
      * Function to get latitude
   * */

   public double getLatitude(){
      if(location != null){
         latitude = location.getLatitude();
      }

      // return latitude
      return latitude;
   }

   /**
      * Function to get longitude
   * */

   public double getLongitude(){
      if(location != null){
         longitude = location.getLongitude();
      }

      // return longitude
      return longitude;
   }

   /**
      * Function to check GPS/wifi enabled
      * @return boolean
   * */

   public boolean canGetLocation() {
      return this.canGetLocation;
   }

   /**
      * Function to show settings alert dialog
      * On pressing Settings button will lauch Settings Options
   * */

   public void showSettingsAlert(){
      AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);

      // Setting Dialog Title
      alertDialog.setTitle("GPS is settings");

      // Setting Dialog Message
      alertDialog.setMessage("GPS is not enabled. Do you want to go to settings menu?");

      // On pressing Settings button
      alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Settings", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
         public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int which) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
            mContext.startActivity(intent);
         }
      });

      // on pressing cancel button
      alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
         public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.cancel();
         }
      });

      // Showing Alert Message
      alertDialog.show();
   }

   @Override
   public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
   }

   @Override
   public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
   }

   @Override
   public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
   }

   @Override
   public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
   }

   @Override
   public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
      return null;
   }
}
```

Comment: Don't use it. It's bad code. There are [more details here](http://gabesechansoftware.com/location-tracking/).

Comment: Because it is terrible androidhive's so called tutorial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main purpose of that is not to be activity lifecycle dependent. Most possibly you do not want to destroy and create a new `GpsTracker` each time user navigates between activities.

Thus, `Services` come into the stage.

Nevertheless, you should strongly consider to evade from such technique in favour of [FusedLocationProviderApi](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/FusedLocationProviderApi), which aims to optimize battery usage.

Comment: Thanks @azizbekian . Can you please elaborate ?

Comment: Sorry, would you rephrase what you mean?

Comment: Of course not, real Service need constructor without parameters, it doesn't need Context as is a Context, and obviously cannot be "started" with operator new not mentioning about that you cannot start dialog in this way from service ... **It is just an example from terrible androidhive's website.**